# Add Page on Navigate Drawer Menu and navigate to respective page on menu click Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I have made a sample with **Navigate Drawer** Menu from **Left** side. I have fixed 4 menu items as (Home, About Us, Enquiry, Contact Us).

Now I need to add pages to my layout, By default it should show **Home Page** with respective content. Then when I would click on **About Us** menu item then should display **About Us Page** with respective content...so on for other menu links too.

I didn't have an idea to how to add page and how should I make menu clickable and to track which menu item should have been clicked and which page should have to open and how.

I have searched a lot for this on google, on YouTube and on several tutorials, but didn't found any proper guidance. Therefore kindly help me regarding this please....

below it the code of MainActivity.cs

```
 using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Support.V4.Widget;
using V7Toolbar = Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;

namespace NavigationDrawerLayout
{
    [Activity(Label = "J&K Tour and Travel", Theme = "@style/Theme.DesignDemo", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {

        DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView;


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);


            // Create ActionBarDrawerToggle button and add it to the toolbar
            var toolbar = FindViewById<V7Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);


            var drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, Resource.String.drawer_open, Resource.String.drawer_close);
            drawerLayout.SetDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
            drawerToggle.SyncState();

            navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
            setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
        }
        void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView)
        {
            navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += (sender, e) => {
                //e.MenuItem.SetChecked(true);
                drawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
            };
        }

        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {

            navigationView.InflateMenu(Resource.Menu.nav_menu);
            return true;

        }



    }
}
```

Also i am sharing a link of .rar file of my whole sample project below. I have made this project using VS 2017 Community Edition using c#:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B584mT-OF6vJZzdFem4tMG9jV1U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to use `NavigationDrawer` with `Fragment` to show different pages.

In your layout you can place a `FrameLayout` for the container of fragments for example:

```cs
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

  <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/framelayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />

  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Then in the `OnCreate` method first commit your home page like this:

```cs
FragmentTransaction transaction = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
HomeFragment home = new HomeFragment();
transaction.Add(Resource.Id.framelayout, home).Commit();
```

Then in the `NavigationItemSelected` event:

```cs
var naviview = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
naviview.NavigationItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
{
    e.MenuItem.SetChecked(true);
    FragmentTransaction transaction1 = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    switch (e.MenuItem.TitleFormatted.ToString())
    {
        case "Home":
            HomeFragment home = new HomeFragment();
            transaction1.Replace(Resource.Id.framelayout, home).AddToBackStack(null).Commit();
            break;

        case "About Us":
            VideoFragment video = new VideoFragment();
            transaction1.Replace(Resource.Id.framelayout, video).AddToBackStack(null).Commit();
            break;
    }
    drawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
};
```

Since it is `Fragment`, then for example, your Home Page should be something like this:

```cs
public class HomeFragment : Fragment
{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your fragment here
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.homelayout, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, how did you got **HomeFragment home = new HomeFragment();** ? I didn't got any method like HomeFragment...

Comment: @SumeetKumar, do you know [Fragments](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/fragments_walkthrough/)? It's kind like `Activity`, they have similar life-cycle.  The `HomeFragment` is a fragement I created as you can see the last code block of my answer, it's like your Home activity (or we can say page), but with `NavigationView`, it is recommended to use a base activity to hold `NavigationView`  and container of fragments, then use `FragmentTransaction` to navigate between different pages.

Comment: @SumeetKumar, I found this [blog](http://www.appliedcodelog.com/2016/01/navigation-drawer-using-material-design.html) for you, similar as my answer, if you find this answer helpful, could you please mark this answer?

Comment: Sir, I have followed the blog that you have suggested. When i have build project...it's succeeded. But when i have debugged it on my Samsung Android mobile while Application debugging it shows me an error as – **Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView** on line **SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);**

Comment: @SumeetKumar, please check your Sumsung's android version, `NavigationView` is added from android api version 22.2. Basically you device version should be android 6.0 or later.

Comment: Sir, now it's ok and application has builded and deployed on mobile. No error while while building and deployment but still not showing **home page** by default and also menu click event is not firing. Why is it so ?...

Comment: @SumeetKumar, did you ever check my answer? Check the second block of code and the third part. Use `FragmentTransaction` to show you fragments and subscribe the `NavigationItemSelected` event for your navigationview.

Comment: `FragmentTransaction transaction = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            HomeFragment home = new HomeFragment();
            transaction.Add(Resource.Id.framelayout, home).Commit();`  Sir I have placed this code in `protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)`. And for menu click I have created `void NavigationItemSelected()
        {var naviview = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);}`

Comment: @SumeetKumar, show me your `HomeFragment` and it's layout. Your home page should be placed here.

Comment: but still not showing up default page and also menu click not firing.

Comment: '[Activity(Label = "Home")]
    public class HomeFragment : Fragment
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.home, container, false);
            return view;
        }
    }'

Comment: @SumeetKumar, try to remove "[Activity(Label = "Home")]" for your home fragment, I don't understand why it doesn't fire by your side, I uploaded [my demo](https://github.com/GraceFeng/NavigationView) and you may have a check. If you find this answer helpful, could you please mark this answer?